# All possible array combinations algorithm (hungarian, bruteforce)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

Got task to resolve (person tracking on computer vision) and i have somehow to get all possible combinations of 2 arrays.
Input: two arrays

```
arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
```

Task is to write (probably recursive) algo to output array of all possible combinations like this:

```
[
  {a:1, b:2, c:3},
  {a:1, b:3, c:2},
  {a:2, b:1, c:3},
  {a:2, b:3, c:1},
  {a:3, b:1, c:2},
  {a:3, b:2, c:1},
]
```

Input arrays may not be same length. For example

```
arr1 = [a,b];
arr2 = [1,2,3];
// => 
[
  {a:1, b:2},
  {a:1, b:3},
  {a:2, b:1},
  {a:2, b:3},
  {a:3, b:1},
  {a:3, b:2}
]
```

Or like this

```
arr1 = [a,b,c];
arr2 = [1,2];
// => 
[
  {a:1, b:2},
  {a:1, c:2},
  {b:1, a:2},
  {b:1, c:2},
  {c:1, a:2},
  {c:1, b:2}
]
```

Perfectly would be structure like this

```
[
  {
    combo: {a:1, b:2, c:3}
  },
  ...
]
```

...but it doesn't really matter

There are lots of topics here on stackoverflow like this, but all those algos are a bit different and easier. They all give something like this:

```
[a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2]
```

I've gotten this so far:

```
const combos = (arr1, arr2, func) => {
    let result = [];
    for(let item1 of arr1){
        let subcombo = {};
        let subArr1 = Object.assign({}, arr1);
        delete subArr1[item1];
        for(let item2 of arr2){
            subcombo[item] = {};
        }
    }
};
function give1() {
    return 1;
}
let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let arr2 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
const res = combos(arr1, arr2, give1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: So... you want SO to do all the work for you? Because I don't see any attempt on your part to solve the task. This is the reason you're not actually asking a question.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so please give it a try yourself first or if you already tried post your code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Basically you're saying "I have this task to do. Internet nerds, do it". Have you tried anything? Show us.

Comment: I believe by this time you might have realized that this is no place for home assignments. Please maintain the quality of questions. Any way, for the sake of answering, please check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cartesian-product-two-sets/)

Comment: so sad you think this way. I kinda spent 1.5 days at this. But every time i try - i'm stucking at something like this:

const combos = (arr1, arr2, func) => {
  let result = [];
  for(let item1 of arr1){
    let subcombo = {};
    let subArr1 = Object.assign({}, arr1);
    delete subArr1[item1];

    for(let item2 of arr2){
      subcombo[item] = {};
    }
  }
};
function give1() {
  return 1;
}

let arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let arr2 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

const res = combos(arr1, arr2, give1);

console.log(res);

And i have no way to improve(

Comment: Also read lots of posts on CV, mathematic equations, but things are so confusing.

Comment: Already tried cartesian - its a bit different, its limited to 2-length results

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question and add what you have tried, and what results you have been getting, even if they are wrong. Show all your efforts if you want anyone to even give it a try.

Comment: @ikebastuz You're looking for the permutations, not the cartesion product, right. Create all the permutations of the longer input, but stop the recursion at the length of the shorter input (so that you don't create duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create function to do permutations with limit and then based on the length of keys and values do the permutation of keys if `keys.length > values.length` otherwise do permutation of values and after that create array of objects from that result.

```js
function permute(data, len) {
  let result = []
  
  function generate(data, n, c) {
    if(!data.length) {
      result.push(c.slice(0, len));
      return;
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      c[n] = data[i]
      let copy = [...data]
      copy.splice(i, 1);
      generate(copy, n + 1, c)
    }
  }
  
  generate(data, 0, [])
  return result;
}

function f(keys, vals) {
  let byKeys = keys.length > vals.length,
  permuted = null
  
  if(byKeys) permuted = permute(keys, vals.length);  
  else permuted = permute(vals, keys.length);
  
  return permuted.map(arr => arr.reduce((r, e, i) => {
    byKeys ? r[e] = vals[i] :  r[keys[i]] = e
    return r;
  }, {}))
}

console.log(f(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]))
console.log(f(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2]))
console.log(f(['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Damn, looks like its works as needed. Have to read it 10 times line by line to put into my head. Thank you, sir, really appreciate it! You are probably a god at codewars ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. It took me some time to figure it out. If you find any problems or bugs let me know.